# svg in CHtmlview (MFC)

Tags: html, svg, mfc

I am not able to draw using SVG in a view derived from CHtmlView in my MFC application. However when I copy the same source in a notepad and open it with Internet explorer, it is working. The version of IE installed on my machine is IE9. Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Did you tried to fill out the complete HTML code incl. DOCTYPE Header? Afaik ist must be xhtml to show svg parts.

Answer (score 3):

The browser control runs in IE7 compatibility mode, so won't support newer features regardless of the IE version installed on your machine.

You can add a meta tag to your HTML to specify the browser version:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Or, you can add a registry entry to make all the browser controls in your app use a particular IE version. See http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version.