# WebBrowser Control trys to download HTML file

Tags: internet-explorer, mfc, browser, webbrowser-control, windows-server

We made an little MFC tool with an embedded WebBrowser Control which loads an local html file with an frameset from the hard drive.

One of our customers reported an error. The error thrown by the webbrowser control is "your current security settings do not allow this file to be downloaded". It seems that the internet explorer control will download the file instead of showing it. This is the first customer who reported the error. The product is nearly 10 years on the market and have thousands of customers. I never heard of the error before.

Can anyone give me an hint where i have to look to solve this problem?

Comment: I suspect that the error message is somewhat spurious, where `downloaded` in this case probably just means `loaded`. Also, the `WebBrowser` control is an instance of IE, and if the user uses a different browser, then IE may be set up with default security settings that preclude the loading of the file. Have a look in `Control Panel > Internet Settings`.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979817/svg-in-chtmlview-mfc

Comment: could not reproduce the problem via internet settings. Now i contacted the customer to get further details.